# Validate URL and display as a link in PHP

Tags: php, validation

When I display the text from database, I want to detect whether that text is URL and if that's with URL format, i want to hyperlink those text automatically.

For example, if my text is like this

"Hey, check this out, i found a great website and i would like to share with you all. Here is the website www.google.com"

So in the above text, I would like to hyperlink www.google.com to www.google.com

Which method should i use to detect url format and adding hyperlink ?

Please kindly suggest. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
function makeClickableLinks($text) {

  $text = eregi_replace('(((f|ht){1}tp://)[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]+)', '<a href="\\1">\\1</a>', $text);

  $text = eregi_replace('([[:space:]()[{}])(www.[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]+)', '\\1<a href="http://\\2">\\2</a>', $text);

  $text = eregi_replace('([_\.0-9a-z-]+@([0-9a-z][0-9a-z-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,3})', '<a href="mailto:\\1">\\1</a>', $text);

  return $text;

}
```

This is the right one ;-) works for all HTTP links (with or without http://) and for e-mail links. Usage `echo makeClickableLinks($string);`

It does not support https as I see, the code is from `http://www.totallyphp.co.uk/code/convert_links_into_clickable_hyperlinks.htm` here and seems to work. At least this kicks you in the right direction.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your solution. I would like to know whether it can detect the string without http:// , for example like www.link.com ?

Comment: oh damn, I provided you with the wrong code! This is for using with BBcodes.. [URL]link[/URL] will be converted. I'll remove this answer and provide you with another!

Comment: Added a replacement. It's just a code from google, but this kicks you the in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

you could use this code snippet:

```
$text = preg_replace('@(https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)@', '<a href="$1">$1</a>', $text);
```

found on [snipplr.com](http://snipplr.com/view/2371/regex-regular-expression-to-match-a-url/)

Answer (score -1):

This can be done with regular expressions. Something along the lines of:

```
echo preg_replace("%((http|https|ftp)://(\S*?\.\S*?))(\s|\;|\)|\]|\[|\{|\}|,|\"|'|:|\<|$|\.\s)%ie", "<a href=\"$1\" target=\"_blank\">$3</a>$4",$text);
```

*Edit: Updated regex

Comment: your regex is only valid for .com,.org and .net domains

Comment: This is poor, what if the domain is .co.uk? .ly? .co? This will fail.